# Jenkins Node Plugin throwing npm-git install error

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins installed on ubuntu and I installed the node Plugin and configured for the latest version of node with npm under the global tool configuration.

I am testing to run a pipeline where i will git clone and do a npm install and a npm test for my repo.

a sample is as below for my pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    environment{
        registry = "xxxx"
        registyCredential = 'harbor'
        dockerImage = ''
    }

    agent any
    tools{
        nodejs "node"

    }
    stages {

        stage('Git clone'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'development', url: 'https://github.com/leeadh/node-jenkins-app-example.git'
            }

        }
        stage('Installing Node') { 
            steps {
                sh 'npm install' 
            }
        }

        stage ('Conducting Unit test'){
            steps{
                sh 'npm test'
            }

        }
```

However, I keep getting a

```
976 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
976 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
976 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
976 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
977 verbose pkgid playground@1.0.0
978 verbose cwd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Compile_Code_CI
979 verbose Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
980 verbose argv "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/bin/node" "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/node/bin/npm" "install"
981 verbose node v11.14.0
982 verbose npm  v6.7.0
983 error file sh
984 error code ELIFECYCLE
985 error errno ENOENT
986 error syscall spawn
987 error playground@1.0.0 install: `npm-git install`
987 error spawn ENOENT
988 error Failed at the playground@1.0.0 install script.
988 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to directly install node JS on to my ubuntu server but it still gives me the same error.

Any help?

PS: a strange thing is that I tried these same exact steps on another jenkins server (this one is running on docker) and it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: can you try to get version first ? see if its installed? npm -v

Comment: hi its 
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# npm -v
3.5.2